# Why do I have to manually 'Restart Management Network' on vSphere 5 host after reboot to get networking available?

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I've got a couple of vSphere 5.0 hosts in a small lab environment here and I've noticed a strange behaviour. When on of the hosts gets rebooted, it is unresponsive to the network until I log into the ESX console, Press `F2` to customize and select `Restart management network`. Once this is done, the networking works perfectly as expected.

Each host has two NICs which are trunked together using Etherchannel to a Cisco 3750. The link is also a .1q VLAN trunk and the management network is configured on VLAN121 with the VM traffic configured on VLAN118.

Why would the host be completely dead to the world until I physically kick it?

### Edit

Sample switch config for trunk:

```
interface Port-channel2
 description Blade 1 EtherChannel Trunk
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
end
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet4/0/1
 description Bladecenter1 CPM 1A
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport mode trunk
 speed 1000
 duplex full
 channel-group 2 mode on
end
```

Vswitch teaming settings:

[image]

Management port group settings:

[image]

Comment: Can you post us your vswitch/port-group settings please?

Comment: I've just noticed that the Mgmt network port group has an MTU of 1500, whereas the Port-Channel interface has an MTU of 9000. Is it possible this is related?

Comment: Possibly, be interesting to see the status of the ports/trunk from the cisco side before and after the reset. BTW I've never seen this kind of problem before and we have many, many host - hence my interest

Comment: Give me a few hours and I'll schedule a reboot to replicate to see what the switch does. I guess that the switchports come back up as 'OK', but will have to test to confirm.

Comment: @growse MTU 9000 is the default for jumbo frames. Port-Chans presumably has Jumbo Frames enabled hence why you are seeing this. Personally, I'd set both at the same frame size. Also, the switches must be configured to use Jumbo Frames. This can be one of the reasons why it 'crashes' until a manual restart.

Comment: Can't seem to edit the above but would also like to add, Jumbo Frames are best used for vMotion transfers to decrease transfer time. So technically if the VMkernal is using the same group as shown in the screenshot, you would definitely benefit by enabling Jumbo Frames.

Different MTU on different port groups should not cause an issue.

Comment: I've got jumbo on the VMkernel for vMotion, but the management is set at 1500.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? having the same problem with esx5.1 on a Dell Blade and using Dell 8024k Switches. Either shutting one LAG member port or the LAG down helps. Restarting management network does not help.

Comment: Sadly not. I've got to keep a manual eye on these hosts whenever they go down for reboot. :(

Answer (score 1):

What kind of NICs are you using?
Have you taken a look if these NICs are listed in the VMWare Compatibility Guide?

http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php
(In "What are you looking for" click "IO Devices")

Also, in your network configuration in vSphere the load balancing property must be set to **Route based on ip hash**

Comment: NICs are Broadcom NetXtreme II BCM5708 1000Base-SX - they were the default in the IBM HS21 blades that I'm using and I believe they're listed on the guide. Nic Teaming Load balancing setting is also set to `Route based on IP hash` for all hosts.

Comment: What happens if you reboot with only one cable from the trunk attached to the switch?

Comment: I don't know Cisco but just to be sure: ESXi (or VMWare in general) only supports static link aggregation. Is the aggregation static or dynamic on your Cisco 3750?

Comment: I've added switch configuration to the question. Trunks are configured statically (I believe) with Etherchannel, but not LACP.

Answer (score 1):

Check that nothing else is sitting on the IP Address allocated to the management network. On boot if it detects something else on that IP address it will not fire up.